# Convex combination of (bounded) random variables can lead to a strictly larger norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, random-variables, convex-analysis, expected-value

Consider an arbitrary non-negative random variable $Z \in L^\infty$ such that $E[Z]=1$ and $\lVert Z \rVert_{2}=2$.

Does there exist a non-negative random variable $Y \in L^\infty$ such that $E[Y]=1$ and $\lVert \lambda Y + (1-\lambda)Z \rVert_{2} > 2$ **for all** $\lambda \in (0,1)$?

My thinking is yes, because the $L^2$-norm of $Y$ can be as large as we like.  But I am finding it difficult to prove.  My idea is that since $Z$ is in $L^\infty$, you can construct $Y$ so that: $Y>Z$ for large values of $Z$, $Y<Z$ for small values of $Z$, and otherwise $Y=Z$ (making sure $\mathbb{E}[Y]=1$).  But writing this down formally is tricky.  Is this the right way to go about it?  Perhaps there is a way of proceeding via contradiction.

Extension: What happens if $Z \in L^2$ (and so not necessarily bounded)?

Comment: Try working with the squares of the norms and using the fact that $||X||_2^2=E[X^2]$. Also, you can let $Y$ be an indicator function of an appropriate set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, e.g., $\Omega=\{\omega_1, \omega_2\}$ and $\mathbb{P}[\{\omega_1\}] = \frac{1}{2}$.  Consider $Z=2\mathbf{1}_{\{\omega=\omega_1\}}$.